# Change DIV CSS attributes when class added to parent DIV?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my website I'm using Bootstrap's JavaScript dropdown modal. When the dropdown is open, the parent DIV of the dropdown and dropdown button trigger has the class "open" added to it. What I'd like to do is set the dropdown button to a default opacity of 0.8 but change it to 1 when the parent has the .open class on it.

I imagine it would look like this:

```
#menu.open > #dropdown-arrow{
    opacity:1 !important; 
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Why not?

Comment: hard to tell without any html, but try removing the `>`. it may not be an immediate child.

Comment: please post a jsfiddle showing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an override use the :not selector

```
#menu:not(.open) > #dropdown-menu {opacity:.8;}
```

P.S. 
Opacity can cause weird problems sometimes. You're better off using rgba to only change the opacity of the background color and border colors.